# Which JAR files are needed to use XPath 3.1 in Saxon EE?

Tags: saxon

If all we're doing ix XPath 3.1 queries against XML & JSON, which of the jar files (if any) do I need along with saxon-ee-10.jar?

- icu4j-59.1.jar
- jline-2.9.jar
- saxon-ee-test-10.1.jar
- saxon-sql-10.1.jar

Comment: I would say you should add the `icu4j-59.1.jar` if you expect your XPath functions like `format-integer`, `format-number` or `format-date` to support various languages or sorting to support various languages, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/installationjava/jarfiles.html for details.

Comment: Thank you. And out of curiosity, what does jline-2.9.jar do?

Comment: David, it is explained further down in the document I linked to.